# What sword is fluctuating next to Arioch in the first volume of the Corum Chronicles?

Tags: chronicles-of-corum

In the *The Chronicles of Corum the Knight of Swords*, illustrated by Mignola and based on the work of Moorcock, during the first encounter of Corum and Arioch (in the first volume), Arioch takes the aspect of a beautiful young man and a black sword fluctuates closed to him.

What incarnation of the black sword is that?

Comment: There was a scene at the end of one of the Elric novels with millions of black swords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the sword changes size when Arioch changes form, it appears that it is not a real manifestation of one the "Black Sword's Brothers" at all.  Rather, it is an appurtenance of Arioch's.

Arioch first appears as a hideous giant, with a black runesword sized to match.

[image: Arioch, page 15]

After a brief interaction with Corum, in this form, he disappears and reappears in a completely different, man-sized, comely form.  The sword also appears to have changed size and now hovers in the air behind the Duke of Hell.

[image: Arioch, page 17]

Having changed along with Arioch, the natural conclusion is that the sword is merely a projection of Arioch himself (or itself).  Arioch can take any form, and part of his form is the menacing image of a black sword—perhaps chosen to frighten Corum, specifically because Arioch knows that one form of the Black Sword will bring so much woe and pain to another manifestation of the Eternal Champion.

We also know, from the fact that, in *Stormbringer*, Elric was able to summon up all the parallel world equivalents of Stormbringer to slay Arioch (banishing the Duke of Hell from that world), that Arioch was not actually the master of any form of the Black Sword.  Had he been, Elric could not have commanded all the half million Black Swords against Arioch and the other two dukes.

(Out of universe, the black sword almost certainly appears alongside Arioch in order to emphasize the fact that Arioch is a character best known from Moorcock's stories about Elric, who has crossed over to play a major role in the Corum tales.)